# Can not run C# CSOM on Linux

Tags: csom

I have some problems with Sharepoint
2013.

I have created a C# application for adding list items to a Sharepoint site. I want to use it on Ubuntu 16.04 but have some errors.

I can use Mono Programs.exe to run application, but I can't use `dmcs Program.cs` to compile it. I get the error below

[image]

> The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'. Are you missing an assemply reference?

Comment: As the error reads, have you added the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` as a reference to your project?

Comment: Licensed only for Windows only. Cannot use this library on Linux legally as far as I'm aware.